# Stable URL to confirm connection JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible it ONLY JavaScript to hit a specified URL and get a reply as to whether it was possible to hit the URL. I do not need the URL content, and any information of the page, all i need is conformation that the URL was reached and it penetrated all custom firewalls that would site in its way.

Comment: JS cannot hit arbitrary URLs via AJAX calls due to the same origin security policy, but you could do somethign like a JSONP call to check if a url is reachable. You might better off dynamically creating an `<img>` tag and see what the status of that request ends up being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You would hit the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) wall.

You really need to do it in the server side. In the JS side, you can then test it by a simple ajax to the server side which returns some boolean. Note that this only tests the connection between the server and the desired URL, not between the client and the desired URL. Not sure if that may form a potential problem for your functional requirement.

Comment: Optionally, call any reliable JSON-P API. If you get results, the URL was reached. Discard the results. If you don't get results, either a firewall blocked you or the API you called is down (very slim chances if you pick a reliable API)

Comment: @xbonez: I don't think that "a specified URL" would be a public JSONP API or have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, otherwise the OP would likely not have asked this question.

Comment: Oh, true. Just re-read the question. My first interpretation was OP merely wanted to test if client has access to internet. In that case, ANY API would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a HEAD request for the URL. That will just return the HTTP header, but not the content.

If this is Javascript in a browser, this should be easy enough using the XMLHTTPRequest object, provided of course that it's in the same domain so that you have access to request the URL at all.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the requested page have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

This feature add crossdomain origins to your document.

BTW, you only can retrieve it with modern browsers, and need the access to requested page (to set this header).

Look at:

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/